# How authenticate redis server using python redis-py?

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, redis

I have to connect remote **redis** server using `redis-py.` 
I have code like this.

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis('user:password@host:9921',db=1)
```

Its not working .

I tried this one too .

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.StrictRedis(host=host,username=username,password=password ,port=6379, db=1)
```

But not working .Basically i want to connect redis hosted in 
**redistogo.com**
How can i connect using python ?

Comment: In the first snippet, I believe the usage should be `redis.StrictRedis.from_url('redis://user:password@host:9921/1')` - you're not calling the right constructor and the URI is not specified correctly. The 2nd snippet is missing a comma after the password but other than that should work IMO. What error message are you getting?